# mysql query compare MAX value and given parameter and return 0 or 1 if max is qual to given one

Tags: mysql, compare, max

i have this UNION query

```
mysql> SELECT gpio_lastevent FROM `GPIO_setup` WHERE gpio_id = 5 UNION select max(gpio_lastevent) from GPIO_setup;
```

the result is:

```
+---------------------+
| gpio_lastevent      |
+---------------------+
| 2015-11-29 14:36:30 |
| 2015-11-29 17:28:47 |
+---------------------+
```

on mysql level I need to compare if MAX is equal to given parameter and return 0 or 1 in another column if true or 0 if false

what i expect as result is:

```
+---------------------+-------------------
| gpio_lastevent      |gpio_latestevent_true
+---------------------+-------------------
| 2015-11-29 17:28:47 |1
+---------------------+-------------------
```

i think this is quite simple, but I cannot figure out how to place query.
thanks for helping out

Comment: More information is needed here. What is the input parameter? Is it the `gpio_lastevent` timestamp or is it the `gpio_id` value?  Your two examples are a little inconsistent in that you want to return `1` if equal and `0` otherwise, but the rows returned by your union query are nonequal - we would then expect your desired result to be `0` for those values, correct?

Comment: gpio_id is only input parameter and it will be always integer. gpio_lastevent's are already in DB. the result should contain gpio_lastevent timestamp for given gpio_id and information if this timestamp is MAX one. i am practically searching for two information giving one input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT
  gpio_lastevent,
  gpio_lastevent=max_lastevent
FROM
  `GPIO_setup` CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(gpio_lastevent) as max_lastevent
                           FROM GPIO_Setup) m
WHERE
  gpio_id = 5
```

here on the subquery I'm getting the last event, then I'm joining this subquery with all rows, then `gpio_lastevent=max_lastevent` will be 1 if the current event is the last event, 0 otherwise.

Comment: just perfect, thanks a lot for prompt response, i got what I need